# How to select latest ID to create new rows in new table in same PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a restaurant in **RESTAURANT** table by inputting the name. RestaurantID(RID) is auto-increment.
but at the same time, i wanted to create a row with the latest added RID in **RATING** Table.

Several questions in other post are unlike my case, i do not know how to solve this problem. Have to seek help from here..

The test result of this code is : **{"success":0,"message":"Fail to create Rating table for this restaurant!"}**

the restaurant name successfully added, but rating table does not work.. Any ideas? or should i do the other way round of adding the RID into rating table?

here's my code:

```
$response = array();  

$name = "test1"; 

if ($rid = addRestaurant($name)){
   echo "$rid"; // now it displays the right id
    if(addRating($rid) == true){
        $response["success"] = 1; 
        $response["message"] = "Restaurant Successfully Created!"; 
        echo json_encode($response); 
    }else{
        $response["success"] = 0; 
        $response["message"] = "Fail to create Rating table for this restaurant!"; 
        echo json_encode($response); 
    }
}else{
    $response["success"] = 0; 
    $response["message"] = "Fail to create Restaurant! Please Try Again Later!"; 
    echo json_encode($response); 
}

function addRestaurant($name){
// mysql inserting a new row 
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO restaurants (Name)VALUES('$name')"); 

// check if row inserted or not 
    if ($result) { 
        $rid = mysql_insert_id();
        echo "$rid"; //this gives me correct RID of "84" latest one.
        return $rid;
    } else { 
        return false;
    }   
}

function addRating($rid){
            echo "$rid"; // here also the latest ID. but why return false?      
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `rating`(`Clealiness`, `Service`, `Quality`, `RID`) VALUES ('0', '0', '0', $rid");
    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy an easy task.

your addRestaurant code should not return true if the query is executed successfully, instead it should return the last inserted id. you are code should be like below

```
$response = array();  

$name = "test1"; 

if ($rid = addRestaurant($name) == true){
    if(addRating($rid) == true){
        $response["success"] = 1; 
        $response["message"] = "Restaurant Successfully Created!"; 
        echo json_encode($response); 
    }else{
        $response["success"] = 0; 
        $response["message"] = "Fail to create Rating table for this restaurant!"; 
        echo json_encode($response); 
    }
}else{
    $response["success"] = 0; 
    $response["message"] = "Fail to create Restaurant! Please Try Again Later!"; 
    echo json_encode($response); 
}

function addRestaurant($name){
// mysql inserting a new row 
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO restaurants (Name)VALUES('$name')"); 

// check if row inserted or not 
    if ($result) { 
        $rid = mysql_insert_id(); //This will return the last inserted id
        return $rid;
    } else { 
        return false;
    }   
}

function addRating($rid){
    //$test = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(RID) FROM restaurants");
    //$return = mysql_fetch_assoc($test); 
    //$rid = $return['MAX(RID)'];

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rating(`Clealiness`, `Service`, `Quality`, `RID`) VALUES (0, 0, 0, $rid");
    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it still showing the same error.. 
may i know is there any mistake in line3 in yr code?

Comment: I just copied your code and made adjustments to it. If may have errors but i cant say with out seeing the error. Can you please enable errors? Place error_reporting(1) at top of that php file, and then edit your post and place the error message you got. This way i will be able to see the error and will assist you accordingly.

Comment: I'd editted the latest version that i tried.. the result is triggering (addRating == true) is false. why is the inserting false? i tried in mySQL 's query, it works.. weird..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do **not** use `mysql_query`! It has been deprecated (or soon will be), and is very easy to introduce [SQL injection vulnerabilities into your code](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Instead, use a library like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

From there, once you execute the INSERT query, [you can retrieve the last inserted ID](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), and use that in another query.

Some pseudocode:

```
$queryObj = $dbHandler->prepare('statement');
$queryObj->execute();
$last_id = $dbHandler->lastInsertId();
$dbHandler->prepare('another statement with $last_id');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! by the way, is that PDO a new type of mySQL coding? because I'm quite a beginner to mysql..

Comment: In a nutshell, PDO is an extension that abstracts the connection to a database server, and automatically handles other tasks such as proper escaping of passed in values. Although it may look intimidating to learn at first, it is worth the effort to learn how it works, as the benefits far outweigh the disadvantages of sticking with `mysql_*` type functions

Answer (score 0):

You Tables structure matter here. If you are working with incremental IDs for the IDs of both tables, you can use mysqli_insert_id (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get your last inserted ID from your first query.

1) Add Restaurant
2) Select your last insert id as done above in your code
3) Append to your rating query

Try Julian H. Lam's PDO as it works well too.